# SQL Server - Number of Rows belonging to key field

Tags: sql-server

How can I get from this table:

```
item_no
-------
A
A
A
A
B
C
C
C
```

to a view that looks like this:

```
item_no   occurrence
-------   ----------
A         1
A         2
A         3
A         4
B         1
C         1
C         2 
C         3
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use row_number over partition by as below:

```
Select Item_No, Row_Number() over(partition by Item_no order by Item_No) as Occurrence from yourtable
```

Comment: Perfect - THANKS

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT item_no, Count(item_no) AS occurrence FROM TableName GROUP BY item_no;
```

Comment: This group the number of items of each type and counts them, he needs to assign a number to each row based on each type.